# Date comparison in postgresql not working

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem with a query in my postresql database. I'm trying to get the last 100 logs after a certain date-time, but when I use this query:

```
select * from log_entry WHERE array['MESSAGE'] && tags AND CAST(last_updated AS DATE) >= '2013-02-28T16:47:26.394213' ORDER BY last_updated DESC LIMIT 100
```

Here the column last_updated is of type: timestamp without time zone

Sometimes I get logs from before '2013-02-28T16:47:26.394213', am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to do this instead of using cast?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, there's your problem: when you cast a timestamp (with or without a time zone) to a date, you truncate the time portion of the timestamp. Why not cast `'2013-02-28T16:47:26.394213'` to a timestamp and compare it directly with `last_updated`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Reposted from a comment by request.)

Well, there's your problem: when you cast a timestamp (with or without a time zone) to a date, you truncate the time portion of the timestamp. Why not cast `'2013-02-28T16:47:26.394213'` to a timestamp and compare it directly with `last_updated`?

```
select * from log_entry 
WHERE array['MESSAGE'] && tags 
AND last_updated 
  >= '2013-02-28T16:47:26.394213'::timestamp without time zone
ORDER BY last_updated DESC LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0):

use this .This should work .

select * from log_entry 
WHERE array['MESSAGE'] && tags 
AND age(last_updated)

> = age(now())
>   ORDER BY last_updated DESC LIMIT 100